# Does the fast Fourier transform have equivalents in other transforms?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform, mellin-transform

I've seen the Mellin transform described as the "multiplicative" analogue to the Laplace transform, as well as the Fourier transform when $x\to\log y$.

Would a discrete Mellin transform be able to take advantage of any of the same optimizations that allow you to reduce the operations in a discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: Does this paper help? they seem to get an algorithm directly expressed in terms of FFT which goes in the way of your question. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224736063_Discrete_Mellin_transform_for_signal_analysis?enrichId=rgreq-e61a91ac016d5c54d14c67db28678a7d-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyNDczNjA2MztBUzo5ODc1NzAzMDk3MzQ1OEAxNDAwNTU2OTIwMDA0&el=1_x_2&_esc=publicationCoverPdf